# Prompt for EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm trying to get a prompt for my EditText to show such as "Please Enter Answer Here" and when the user taps on the EditText to type thier Answer the text should disappear and be blank for them to enter their answer in.

As of right now this is what I have for my .xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AnswerActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittxt_answer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my .java

```
public class AnswerActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer);

    EditText ans = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt_answer);
    //Continue with acitivty.... 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `android:hint` attribute and you won't need any code for that.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittxt_answer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:hint="Please Enter Answer Here" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called [hint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ahint) you can set it in your xml with `android:hint` or in java with `setHint()`

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/edittxt_answer"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:hint="Please enter your answer here" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
android:hint="@string/answer_hint"
```

in your XML